# Prevent Sublime Text from including .sublime-workspace files in search

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Here is my `Preferences.sublime-settings` file:

```
{
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "remember_open_files": true,
    "folders":
    [
        {
         "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.sublime-workspace"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I search all of my open files and folders in the sidebar (cmd-shift-f) I still get search results including workspace files which live in one of the directories which I have open. For instance, if I have `~/foo` open and there's a file `~/foo/bar/hello.sublime-workspace`, it gets included in the search results.

How do I get Sublime to ***never*** include `.sublime-workspace` files in my searches?

Comment: `file_exclude_patterns` concerns files showing up in the sidebar, not the search.  Use @Andre Dion's second solution, and add `*.sublime-workspace` to the `binary_file_patterns` list.

Comment: @AGS That comment adds a lot. I wish you had made it a standalone answer so I could give you some rep.

Comment: I found that the `file_exclude_patterns` trick does work for me only if the *Where* field is completely empty in the search. Once I add items into the *Where* field, the workspace file is included in the search

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments [here](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/97052-find-in-files-exclude-directories/) it looks like you have two possible solutions:

1. Use a negated pattern in the "Where:" field of "Find in Files...": `-*.sublime-workspace`
2. In your settings file in the `"folders"` section, add `"binary_file_patterns": ["*.sublime-workspace"]`

---

**Edit**

Actually, you may just need to specify a `"path"` for your `"file_exclude_patterns"`:

```
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "./",
        "file_exclude_patterns": [".sublime-workspace"]
    }
]
```

From http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html:

> **Each folder must have a path**, and may optionally have a folder_exclude_patterns and file_exclude_patterns setting.

Comment: I had `"path": "."` before, so maybe that's what the problem was.

Comment: any idea what "." binds to here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter by appending "**,-*.sublime-workspace**" to your directory next to **Where:**

For example, set **Where** to

```
<project>,-*.sublime-workspace
```

to search all your project directories, or

```
c:\mydir,-*.sublime-workspace
```

to search a specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the question title but for a problem that can come up in project-level configuration.

It's [a reported bug that binary_file_patterns does not work on a per-project basis.](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/124477-binary_file_patterns-in-project-settings-doesnt-work/) Except it sometimes does. In any case, this worked for me when I moved the workspace exclusion, for a project, from binary_file_patterns to file_exclude_patterns.

Another issue you may be unaware of is that if you open the directory with `subl .`, it does not load the project. You need to go to "Sublime > Project" and "open project" for the settings to take effect. Yes, this is terrible.